# How can I add this kind of edge to a circle? (biting effect)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have this flex container which has three circles and I want the first one to have a bite effect on the right, the middle one normal and the last circle a bite on the left.
I tried putting another circle on top of another and just adding margin to it but it doesn't work for the third circle. Any idea how I can do this?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 20px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.box1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.add-edge-right {
  margin-left: 250px;
  background-color: white;
}

.add-edge-left {
  margin-right: 250px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="box1 add-edge-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="box1 add-edge-left"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You could look into using a background-image which is a radial-gradient in white and positioned to the right (for the first 'bite') and to the left (for the second 'bite'). That way you wouldn't have to add otherwise unnecessary elements to the DOM.

Comment: Do you want the bite to be transparent?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the 'bite' to be transparent, for example so a background shows through, then you can use CSS mask.

In this snippet the width of the elements has been set at a CSS variable so you can easily change it if required as is the amount you want the bite 'offset' - to make it bigger or smaller.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
  <style>
    .container {
      --w: min(300px, 30vw);
      --r: calc(var(--w) / 2);
      --x: calc(var(--w) / 3);
      /* the amount to displace the mask */
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      gap: min(20px, calc((100vw - (3 * var(--w))) / 2));
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .box1 {
      aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
      width: var(--w);
      background-color: blue;
      border-radius: 50%;
      z-index: 10;
    }
    
    .box1:nth-child(1) {
      -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at calc(var(--w) + var(--x)), transparent var(--r), black var(--r));
      mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at calc(var(--w) + var(--x)), transparent var(--r), black var(--r));
    }
    
    .box1:nth-child(3) {
      -webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at calc(-1 * var(--x)), transparent var(--r), black var(--r));
      mask-image: radial-gradient(circle at calc(-1 * var(--x)), transparent var(--r), black var(--r));
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box1">
    </div>
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box1"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Excellent, configurable and really portable solution!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest another way than flex.
old school one with relative, absolute position and border
(don't forget the box-sizing otherwise it's not working)

If you want to change the size, for exemple container from 600 to 900:

- container width 900px
- box1 width, height 300px
- box1:nth-child(2), several changes:
  we'll put border to 50px, so 50 each side -> width, height 400px
  top -50px (height of the border)

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}

.box1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.box1:first-child {
  left: 0;
}

.box1:nth-child(2) {
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  top: -30px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 11;
  border: 30px solid white;
}

.box1:last-child {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if the page has a background image? The white border would be obsolete in such case. (Well, that depends on OP's use-case, but would be a nice addition to the answer.)

Comment: if it's a color in background, you still can play with border color to match the background color. If it's an image this structure won't work! I think the best would be to use svg with clip-mask